# Converting vertexed curve into true curve using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, true-curves

I'm looking for a method for reshaping parcel polygons in large-scale database. I am dealing with cadastral data as shown in the picture and I need to convert the vertexed curves to true curves to reduce the vertices number and improve the performance during the editing process. The polygons originated from CAD.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If you have at least a **STANDARD** licensed install of ArcMap then you can use the Smooth Polygon tool in the cartography toolbox. Be aware that you cannot create Bezier curves if your source data is a shapefile.

If the line can be represented with a single curve then I think it will do this otherwise it converts it to a set of curves so you may not get the desired reduction in vertices, just something to be aware of.

Comment: I think it best answer if asker wants to use a tool for this issue if you just use arcgis software. Without this metbod you should edit manually all vertices.